# Getting the the input value after focus out

Tags: php, forms, for-loop, input

I want to add a number of input fields in form which depends on value of previous input fields.
For example:
I have two inputs

if user

```
1.<tr><td>Number of Articles/Posts/Pages:</td><td><input type="number" name="count" ></td></tr>


2.<tr><td>Keywords:</td><td><?php 
$number_of_keywords=$_POST['count'];
i="<input type='text' name='keyword'>";
i++;
i==$number_of_articles;
echo i;
        ?></td></tr>
```

For example if user type 3 in count field, then i want to show 3 input field. Number of input fields depend on how much user type in count field.

Please tell me that if this above code will work here and how can i get the count field value at run time?

Comment: Uhm ... what kind of language is this? This isnt php for sure.

Comment: do you want to do this in one page or do you want to populate fields after 'count' is posted?

Comment: Are you trying to create the inputs dynamically or after form submit?

Comment: I want to create inputs before form submissions. For example: if user input 3 in count field field then there should 3 inputs fields to type at next line.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't get the count field value at run time, the value must be submitted via a form or passed as a parameter in a query string, so that PHP knows about it.

This question is more appropriated to be tagged as a javascript question, than a PHP question. if you want to do it at run time. If you would like to do it strictly using PHP, then you will have to pass the count value to the server somehow, either by submitting a form, or by sending it via a parameter in a query string, as I have told you before.

Please take into consideration that if this is your real code, it will create n inputs with the attribute

```
    name="keyword"
```

which is not correct and it might get you into a lot of problems later on.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use some JS and a php file for this.

What i would do is have an onchange on the first input like

`<input type="number" name="count" onchange="getval(this);">`

The getval is a JS function that it will according to the input fill in a class with the according number of inputs you like.

```
function getval(sel){
    var load = $.get('yourPHPFILE.php',{number:sel.value);
    $(".someClass").html('Refreshing');
    load.error(function() {
      console.log("Mlkia kaneis");
      $(".someClass").html('failed to load');
      // do something here if request failed
    });
    load.success(function( res ) {
      console.log( "Success GET VA" );
      $(".someClass").html(res);
    });
    load.done(function() {
      console.log( "Completed GET VA" );
    });
}
```

You then in the php file get the value by `$_GET['number']`
and with a loop there you `echo` the according number of inputs you like.
`someClass` is going to be the class that you would like to populate with the inputs.